# Как прилинковать нестандартную версию boost через cmake (не хедеронли часть).

Tags: c++, boost, cmake, линковка

Есть проект под arm который компилируется и собирается на х86ой машине (кросскомпиляция). Есть версия библиотеки boost собранная под arm. С boost мне нужен asio.   Я использую CMake но команда find_package мне не подходит т. к. она подцепит вариант который на машине. Я пытаюсь подключить библиотеку прописав пути напрямую но получаю ошибку:

```
error: undefined reference to `boost::system::generic_category()'
```

Cmake скрипт:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.1)
project(AAA)
add_executable(
    ${PROJECT_NAME} ${SRC_LIST} 
    "main.cpp" 
    )
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++17 -Wall -pthread ") #-lboost_system
# Подключение Boost
#set(Boost_USE_STATIC_LIBS OFF)       # Использует статический вариант библиотеки ()
#set(Boost_USE_MULTITHREADED OFF)    # Используем только один поток(нам нужно что бы весь asio крутился на одном ядре). 
include_directories("/home/mrfieldy/linaro_work/target_lib/boost_1_67_0/")
link_directories("/home/mrfieldy/linaro_work/target_lib/boost_1_67_0/libs/")
target_link_libraries(AAA "/home/mrfieldy/linaro_work/target_lib/boost_1_67_0/libs/")
```

Cmake 3.1; GСС 7.2;
boost 1.67;
Kubuntu 18.04;
IDE Qt Creator 4.6.2.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`target_link_libraries` принимает библиотеки (файлы) в качестве аргументов, а не директории. Поэтому передавайте в неё правильные файлы библиотек.

---

Ну а если делать по уму, то нужно использовать `find_package`, предварительно выставив `BOOST_ROOT` в тот путь, где требуемый boost находится.

Comment: спасибо, сейчас тогда буду копать в сторону BOOST_ROOT

Comment: @mrFieldy, смотрите документацию [FindBoost](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.8/module/FindBoost.html)

Comment: Получилось сделать как по уму `set (Boost_USE_STATIC_LIBS OFF)
set (Boost_USE_MULTITHREADED ON)
set (Boost_NO_SYSTEM_PATHS ON)
set (BOOST_ROOT "/home/mrfieldy/linaro_work/target_lib/boost_1_67_0/")
find_package(Boost REQUIRED system)
include_directories (SYSTEM ${Boost_INCLUDE_DIR})
link_directories(${Boost_LIBRARIES})
target_link_libraries(AAA ${Boost_LIBRARIES})`